predicates in different domain
I am having trouble with this question. It basically provides some predicates, and we have to express the statement using quantified logical expression in two different ways, one in each provided domain. I have no problem answering the question in the first domain(Students in the class), but I do not really understand how to answer for the second domain(all people in the world).
In this question, use the predicates and domain definition below:
(): " has a laptop."
(): " has a desktop computer."
(): " uses macOS."
(): " uses Windows."
Domain 1: Students in this class
Domain 2: All people in the world
For each of the following statements (a-d), express the statement using quantified logical expressions in two different ways, one in each provided domain. You may define additional predicates wherever required.
a. Some students have both a laptop and a desktop computer
b. All students who use macOS have a laptop
c. Every student uses either macOS, Windows or both

For Domain 1: Students in the class
To represent statement a(Some students have both a laptop and a desktop computer) We can represent it as

 \begin{align} \exists x (L(x) \land D(x)) \end{align}

To represent statement b(All students who use macOS have a laptop)
We can represent it as

 \begin{align} \forall x (M(x) \rightarrow L(x)) \end{align}

To represent statement c(Every student uses either macOS, Windows or both)
We can represent it as

 \begin{align} \forall x (M(x) \lor W(x)) \end{align}

For Domain 2: All people in the world
Let $S(x)$ denote that 'x is in the class'
Now,
To represent statement a(Some students have both a laptop and a desktop computer) We can represent it as

 \begin{align} \exists x (S(x) \land L(x) \land D(x)) \end{align}

To represent statement b(All students who use macOS have a laptop)
We can represent it as

 \begin{align} \forall x (S(x) \land M(x) \rightarrow L(x)) \end{align}

To represent statement c(Every student(in the world) uses either macOS, Windows or both)
We can represent it as

 \begin{align} \forall x (S(x) \rightarrow (M(x) \lor W(x))) \end{align}

Hope it Helps!
